# Gradle initialization operations (loading, parsing, checking classes)

Tags: gradle

I saw in my gradle build that it's do some initialization at the beginning of the build. For example:

```
:compileJava
[search path for source files: ..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.guava\guava-gwt\14.0.1\jar\de1f56fc5149d9e80c0e5107493370db2fa2d5e9\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar,..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jar\40719ea6961c0cb6afaeb6a921eaa1f6afd4cfdf\jsr305-1.3.9.jar,..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.guava\guava\14.0.1\bundle\69e12f4c6aeac392555f1ea86fab82b5e5e31ad4\guava-14.0.1.jar]
[search path for class files: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\resources.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\rt.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\jsse.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\jce.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\charsets.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\jfr.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\classes,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar,..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.guava\guava-gwt\14.0.1\jar\de1f56fc5149d9e80c0e5107493370db2fa2d5e9\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar,..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jar\40719ea6961c0cb6afaeb6a921eaa1f6afd4cfdf\jsr305-1.3.9.jar,..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.guava\guava\14.0.1\bundle\69e12f4c6aeac392555f1ea86fab82b5e5e31ad4\guava-14.0.1.jar]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.guava\guava-gwt\14.0.1\jar\de1f56fc5149d9e80c0e5107493370db2fa2d5e9\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar(com/google/common/base/Optional.java)]]
[parsing started ZipFileIndexFileObject[..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.guava\guava-gwt\14.0.1\jar\de1f56fc5149d9e80c0e5107493370db2fa2d5e9\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar(com/google/common/base/Optional.java)]]
[parsing completed 0ms]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.guava\guava-gwt\14.0.1\jar\de1f56fc5149d9e80c0e5107493370db2fa2d5e9\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar(com/google/common/collect/AbstractIterator.java)]]
[parsing started ZipFileIndexFileObject[..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.guava\guava-gwt\14.0.1\jar\de1f56fc5149d9e80c0e5107493370db2fa2d5e9\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar(com/google/common/collect/AbstractIterator.java)]]
[parsing completed 0ms]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/String.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.guava\guava-gwt\14.0.1\jar\de1f56fc5149d9e80c0e5107493370db2fa2d5e9\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar(com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java)]]
[parsing started ZipFileIndexFileObject[..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.guava\guava-gwt\14.0.1\jar\de1f56fc5149d9e80c0e5107493370db2fa2d5e9\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar(com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java)]]
[parsing completed 134ms]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.guava\guava-gwt\14.0.1\jar\de1f56fc5149d9e80c0e5107493370db2fa2d5e9\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar(com/google/common/annotations/GwtCompatible.java)]]
[parsing started ZipFileIndexFileObject[..\.gradle\caches\artifacts-24\filestore\com.google.guava\guava-gwt\14.0.1\jar\de1f56fc5149d9e80c0e5107493370db2fa2d5e9\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar(com/google/common/annotations/GwtCompatible.java)]]
[parsing completed 0ms]
```

Why gradle parses sources files which are in classpath (jars)? And how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The log message (which doesn't appear to come from Gradle) prints the Java compiler's source path (which defaults to the compiler's class path). If you do not want source files on the class path to be processed, you can do:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs = ["-implicit:none"]
}
```

Comment: Peter, I checked it and it didn't help. If it doesn't directly come from Gradle it may come from gradle's java plugin.

Comment: Peter, I should also write that this log has been generated after I added `options.warnings=true` and `options.verbose=true`

Comment: The message comes from the Java compiler itself. What concrete problem are you trying to solve? If `-implicit:none` doesn't help (which is surprising), you'd have to provided a minimal reproducible example. It's really more a Java compiler than a Gradle question.